# Any way to get the assembly compilation of a python program on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi4

I am curious to see how efficient the assembly code generated by the python compiler on my raspberry pi is, so I am wondering if there is a way to get the ARM Assembly file.

Comment: Python is not a compiled language.

Comment: For more about how Python (well, the default CPython implementation, at least) works under the hood (it generates bytecode, not assembly), see https://opensource.com/article/18/4/introduction-python-bytecode

Comment: you dont use python if you are interested in performance. (nor JAVA nor a long list of other languages).